# mvc3 is there a way to get value of a PartialView textbox with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a partialView that is embedded on my page and it has certain a certain textbox that I would like to get the value of and put into another textbox, since this is a PartialView the code does not show on PageSource so I was wondering is there a possible way to extract the value ?
This is my code

```
       // Jquery that triggers the form to submit to allow PartialView
  <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#form0').trigger('submit');



    });
   </script>
  // The triggered ajax form
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("feeds", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "globe",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "GET",
OnSuccess = "fillTextBox"
}))
            {
                @Html.TextBox("zips", "", new { style = "width:120px;margin-right:10px;", Value = @Model.profile.zip })
                @Html.DropDownList("rad", new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{
                  new{ Text = "10", Value= 10},
                   new{ Text = "30", Value= 30}}, "Value", "Text"))
                  @Html.DropDownList("TypeFeed", new SelectList(new List<Object>{new { Text = "Breaking News", Value = "Breaking News"}}, "Value", "Text"))
                <input  type="submit" value="Find" />



            }
      <div id="globe" style="float:left">
    </div>
```

as you can see the partialView lies inside the Global and within that PartialView there is a textbox

```
    @Html.TextBox("longitude", (Object)@ViewBag.longitude)
```

that textbox has a value that I would like to transfer to another textbox on my page

```
<input type="text" id="myname" />
```

is there any possible way I can transfer the value of longitude to myname ?

Answer (score 0):

A partial view will still render into HTML on the client side, so your jQuery doesn't need to know that it was a partial view at all.  So, in your view, you could do $("#myname") or $("#longitude") and it will find them in the DOM just fine.

Comment: I have tried                                                          var partialValue = $('#longitude').val();  
            $('#myname').val(partialValue);                           to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Scottie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495247/scottie) has said, your partial view will ultimately load into the DOM which should be fine for jquery to get access of your content lies within any partial view rendered on page.

if you are not getting the value then try the other way around. You are triggering the submit on `document ready`. Try submitting the form by native form submitting method i.e. on submit button click. `fillTextBox` would probably doing this,

```
function fillTextBox()
{
  var textBoxValue = $('#longitude').val();
  $('#myname').val(textBoxValue);
  console.log($('#myname').val());
}
```

This should get the desired value `OnSuccess` on successful form submition. Hope this helps.